# How to deploy a custom ribbon tab across Root Sub-Levels?

Tags: ribbon, custom-actions

I have a custom ribbon tab that works perfectly on the root Site, e.g.

www.site.com/Lists/MainContentType/AllItems.aspx

But it does not work on subsites e.g.

www.site.com/contentTypeMainList/example/Lists/levelContentType/AllItems.aspx

I have defined the Custom Ribbon as

```
<CustomAction
      Id="CustomRibbonListsActionsTab"
      RegistrationType="ContentType"
      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
      Rights="ManageLists"
      RegistrationId="0x01">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you deploying it as a `Site` scope feature?  If it's a `Web` scope feature then you have to activate it on the relevant subsites.

For any customizations with Ribbon, make sure to clear the browser's cache to see the changes.